# Saving form without internet

Tags: javascript, forms, storage

I'm creating an office pool on the computer. No internet is available. I have designed each person a page (using the same computer) where they make their selection by radio button and assign points with a text box. but I cannot figure a way, when they click either 'submit' or 'save' that the radio button and points will remain.

What I'm hoping is that once they close the browser and decide to recheck or change their selection, that when they re-open their webpage all their previous radio button selection and points will still be there.

I have tried a little javascript but nothing seems to work. I have also tackled with localStorage but can't seem to make it work (not sure if I'm doing something wrong as everytime I close the browser and restart it all the selections are lost)

Sorry if this question was asked but couldn't seem to find one with my specification with no internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated as kick off time is around the corner.

Comment: It can easily be done if systems are connected thru LAN.

Comment: Of course the information won't be kept, you need to save the data to a persistent data structure such as DB, file etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Achieving offline mode**

You should be able to achieve offline mode with it [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Take a look on [Local Storage And How To Use It On Websites tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) or ["Let's Take This Offline"](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/offline.html) chapter in Mark Pilgrim's (online) book Dive Into HTML5 ( very nice overview of writing offline web apps with HTML5 technologies).

After getting familiar with information above it would be much clearer for you of how to use localStorage.

**Storage Frameworks**

Consider using of JS wrappers of localStorage...
Listing some JS Libraries for working with localStorage below:

- [PersistJS](http://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js), which uses the 
  local storage of the browser to keep track of data.
- [Lockr](https://github.com/tsironis/lockr) - is a wrapper for the localStorage API and lets you use a number of useful methods and features.
- [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js) - wrapper for the localStorage, provides deeper browser support via fallbacks.